# How to have assert()s that depend on debug-only code compile in a Release build?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, assert

Wait! - this is not as silly a question as it sounds.  The title is simply succinct.

I have some debugging code to verify the correctness of a data structure and some assertions checking this correctness, which I only want enabled in the Debug build:

```
{$ifdef DEBUG}
  function Sorted : Boolean;
  function LinearSearchByValue(const T : TType) : NativeInt;
{$endif}
```

and later in a method:

```
assert(Sorted);
```

for example.

In my debug build with assertions enabled, all is fine.  However, in my Release build with assertions *disabled*, the line `assert(Sorted);` causes a compiler error `E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Sorted'`.  It's quite right, the identifier isn't declared, but assertions are also turned off and should not be being evaluated or have any code generated.  (Trying to trick assert by declaring the method but having no implementation causes the normal error 'Unsatisfied forward or external declaration'.  It is clearly looking for the method body as well.)

This is leading to some messy code where methods that should not exist in a Release build at all have to be declared and have a body, in order to compile asserts, which are turned off.

**How do I declare methods that exist only in a debug build, and use those in assertions which should also only exist in the debug build, in Delphi 2010?**

Further info:

- I tried wrapping the method declarations with `{$ifopt C+}`, which checks if assertions are switched on.  The calls to `assert` still failed with 'undeclared identifier'.
- Compiler options are definitely that assertions are turned off.  (I checked :))
- I have tried wrapping calls to `assert` that use these methods with `{$ifdef DEBUG}`.  However, this is messy and should not be required.  At one point it made me worried that assertions are being compiled even in Release builds, and for performance reasons I don't want them at all.  (This is not happening - assert code is not generated.)
- My current strategy is to declare these methods all the time, but in a Release build ifdef the method body out and fill it with a dummy Result. The aim here is to all assertions to compile, but have as little overhead for the methods as possible, and their return value (should they have turned out to be actually called in a release build) to be clearly wrong.
- Is there any equivalent to C/C++-style macros in Delphi, where an `ASSERT(x)` macro would simply be defined as nothing in a release build, causing the compiler to neither see nor care about the statement inside the assertion?  This is one of the few clean ways (IMO) to use macros in C++.

So while asserts are not being generated, they are compiled.  This loops back to my question: How do I best mix debug-only methods and assertions, and release builds?

Comment: I think you've already enumerated your options. You just need to decide which one to use.

Comment: That's a shame - I was hoping it was a compiler bug or I was missing something obvious.  I've chosen the one 'my current strategy is...' at the moment, but it's still not perfectly clean as such.

Comment: I wouldn't use dummy result, I'd `raise EAssertionFailed` since you should never get there. In fact I have a utility function named `RaiseAssertionFailed` to do just that.

Comment: It is absolutely pointless to raise EAssertionFailed w/o having Assert to "capture" a line number.

Comment: @User, you don't need an `Assert` statement to get line numbers from an exception.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, you are incorrect. `Assert` compiler magic has unique properties not available otherwise and is right tool for checking always-true conditions.

Comment: My previous comment is correct, @User. Mad Except, JclDebug, and Eureka Log *all* allow a program to discover file names, line numbers, and *lots* of additional information from an exception, and *none* requires the use of `Assert` to get it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: an exception is a good idea.  But, ideally and ideologically (not pragmatically) I don't want to raise an exception at runtime for what (IMO) should be enforced at compile-time.

Comment: You won't raise exception at runtime, because you won't ever call that code. My code is littered with such things. For example the else clause of a case statement for an enumerated type. I always put `RaiseAssertionFailed` in there. And of course it never executes. Apart from when I make a mistake. And then I find out about it. Which is what I want.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, no it is not. You are miscomparing code generation feature with proprietary debug symbol tables (you forgot a TD format) for the whole binaries. There is no point in reinventing the wheel with debug symbols while you already have a `Assert`, smooth and round (and applicable to free builds too!). Look closely at the codegen output from assertion.

Comment: @David Heffernan, `else Assert(False, yourmsg)` will perform the same way but will give more valuable information at failure.

Comment: @user539484 Not it won't. It will be compiled out of `C-` builds.

Comment: @David Heffernan, why do you want `EAssertionFailed` after disabling  assertions explicitly?

Comment: @user539484 Well, it reads better than `Assert(False)`. It doesn't have a performance cost. And in the scenario described in the question, instead of the dummy result I think it is better to say, *thou shall not pass*.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I agree what `RaiseAssertionFailed` looks slightly better than `Assert(False)`, but cost is losing module name and line number. Also, the flexibility is lost too, you can no longer insert or remove assertion checks at will during full or partial builds.

Comment: @user539484 Since I have madExcept, I don't pay that cost

Comment: @David Heffernan, you still pay flexibility cost and implicit complexity of reinvented wheel (see the rant above) cost, also burdened with symbol table.

Comment: Now I don't understand. Never mind.

Comment: Feel free to post a question, but please keep in mind what internals of madExcept are being kept in secret, so stick to the general or open (Jcl, Vasbotn) solutions.

Comment: @user539484 What secret? Mathias ships source. And what question would I ask? "How do I parse the comments of @user539484?"  ;-)

Comment: @David Heffernan, question *what to ask* exactly should be directed to the one who pretends he *does not understand* :p

Comment: @user539484 Maybe it is me. But I cannot understand how you assert that this statement is false: *you don't need an Assert statement to get line numbers from an exception*. And as for the rest, I don't perceive a flexibility cost since I don't want flexibility when I write that code. When I want flexibility, I write `Assert()`. When I want a runtime check that I want performed at all times, `Assert()` is no good.

Comment: @David Heffernan, glad you've chosen to be more constructive in the discussion. OK, `Assert` intrinsic preserves module name and line number of its invocation. In the contrast, 3rd party solutions can **extract** module name and line number from the **debug information** (that is, linker generated MAP files or Turbo Debugger symbols). Obviously, to make it work you have to preserve this information, and due its nature this information will cover an entire executable. That was my point on simple vs. complex and light-weight vs. burden.

Comment: @user539484 Fair enough. In my case I have madExcept already in place. It does so much more. It gives stack traces. Information on unanticipated errors. You know all that though. Rob's statement was accurate. You are not correct in disputing it.

Comment: @User, your claim is that manually raising `EAssertionFailed` without using `Assert` is "pointless" because it doesn't give line numbers. My counterclaim is that it's possible to get line numbers without using `Assert`. My implication is that manually raising the exception is *not* pointless — it's still possible to retrieve useful information about the source of the exception. You might *now* say that your point was about complexity and weight, but you haven't mentioned those things before now. Many of us don't care about weight, and complexity is irrelevant when packaged in a good library.

Comment: @David Heffernan, on flexibility: if you once upon the time decide what some stable code should no longer check such *should-never-happen* branches, you can remove the instrumentation w/o making any edits to the code in question. And again, Assert is self-contained, manual exception throwing requires some 3rd party assistance to produce a report as useful as out-of-box Assert produces.

Comment: @Both opponents: ok, here is another point: very core feature vs. separate extension. And an another: JclDebug and TD symbols are merely a data written beyond end of image, thus not Microsoft PE format compliant (no idea about EurekaLog and madExcept symbols, tho).

Comment: @user madExcept information can be embedded as a resource, or as I do, kept private to the developer and separate from the program.

Comment: @David Heffernan, ... and therefore *it works on my system* :) And then you really need an sensible error message, binary built with `-C-` proudly reports "EAssertionFailed" with no additional info :)

Comment: @user539484 No, it reports something else. But it never happens anyway.

Comment: @David Heffernan, how can it "never happen" and "report something else" at the same time?

Comment: @user539484 That's the thing with assertions isn't it.

Comment: @David Heffernan, so you dont care about additional info hoping what it never happen anyway? Good point.

Comment: @user539484 I get loads more info than I would from a failed `Assert`. Since I use madExcept. Don't expect me to choose `Assert` for the situations where madExcept is not available. Since I know what's in my code, I know that madExcept is there.

Comment: @David Heffernan, probably you were using Assert incorrectly, as you are incorrectly using madExcept now. Hence: no satisfaction, confusion, desire to reinvent.

Comment: @user Thank you for your advice. You are right. I am using madExcept incorrectly. All the detailed bug reports I receive are useless to me. I'd be better off stripping it out. Indeed I am dis-satisfied. I am confused. I'm stricken with re-invention fever. If only I'd come to you for help and advice. I wish I could understand Assert. It's just too complex for me.

Answer (score 5):

Don't exclude the code from your release build. Keep the code there, and have it compiled unconditionally.

Your argument against having the code exist in a release build is that it's "messy." But you've already written the code, so it's going to be messy whether it's compiled or not. You may as well let the compiler compile it; it doesn't take appreciably longer to compile the extra code, after all.

Trying to exclude the assertion-related code only makes your code *messier* by requiring conditional-compilation directives.

Assertions and debug information are orthogonal settings. Assertions can be enabled when debugging is not, and vice versa.

An alternative is to move your assertion-related code into your unit tests. Then they're automatically excluded from all versions of your application, but they're still available for testing.

Comment: Even in $C- state, Assert and its arguments are participating in compilation process, so one cannot have undeclared symbol even if Assert call will generate no code in $C-. So the solution is `{$IFOPT C+}Assert(ThisSymbolHasToBeDeclared){$ENDIF}`.

Comment: Yes, @User, they are participating in compilation, but so what? I'm not suggesting having any undeclared symbols. I'm suggesting have *no* conditional compilation at all. Keep `Sorted` declared normally, and call it normally in `Assert` statements. The compiler will not generate any object code.

Comment: I agree with Rob. Let the compiler compile it. Since you dont' refer to it in your release build, the linker will just toss it away.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I partially agree - trusting the compiler not to link them in is often ok. But the conditional compilation in this case is because the methods are not part of the normal class's interface.  They are for debug-time checking only, and it would be dangerous for them to be accidentally included in Release code. Thus they're ifdefed to only be present for Debug. IMO it should be impossible for those methods to exist for a release build: not declared, not implemented, not in the IDE insight, etc. This might be a special case, but I doubt it's so rare a case that it's generally invalid.

Comment: @DavidM If you want to keep these internal methods out of the public interface seen by clients in the release build, mark these methods as private, or move them into an interface implemented by your class.

Comment: It seems your issue is that you're asserting things that are expensive to calculate. That's unfortunate. Consider doing that in a unit test instead. Then you can remove the debugging code from your program entirely, making it impossible to call accidentally. When there's no longer testing code in your program, then you can be more confident that the code you ship is the same as the code you tested.

Comment: @dthorpe: Thanks.  They're already private, which does restrict them to that unit only.

Comment: @DavidM So if they're private, where is the "danger" of including them in Release code? Consumers of your classes can't call these methods if they are private.

Comment: @dthorpe: I could call them, by accident!  Just because they're not directly accessible to an external unit doesn't mean that, if compiled and present, they can't be used. That's why they were ifdef-ed for debug builds only, so a release build will fail. A compile-time error is much better (IMO) than the runtime error that would occur with all the suggestions above.

Comment: Also for a while the fact that asserts required the statements inside made me think that assertions were in the compiled code (the compiler wanted their contents!), despite the assertions-off compiler flag.  That would have been bad.  It turns out that even though the compiler uses them they aren't in the generated code, but until I checked that no assert code was emitted it did create a slight worried feeling.

Answer (score 3):

Assertions are usually "elided" or not included in the output executable code at the link step in the compile process. The source code symbols and expressions passed into the assert function must be defined in the compile step so the the compiler can parse and generate code for the assertion and its expression parameter.

Whether the assert is included in the output exe is determined by the linker when copying code to the output file. Depending on the compiler, the expression passed to the assert might still be included in the executable code even if the call to the assert function isn't included.

As noted in other answers and many comments, asserts are not exclusive to debugging. Asserts are also valuable in release code, to verify that must-never-happen conditions don't.

One solution to allow you to leave assertions in your release code while making the functions used in the assertion expression exist only in debug builds is to define do-nothing stubs of the debug functions for the release build.  Like this:

```
// Declaration:
  private function Sorted: Boolean;

// Implementation

{$ifdef DEBUG}
  function Sorted : Boolean;
  begin
// work work work
  end;
{$else}
  function Sorted: Boolean;
  begin
  end;
{$endif}


// used in an assertion:

  assert(Sorted);
```

This allows you to use the assertions in debug code and in release code without polluting your source code with ifdef wrappers around the assertions, and guarantees that the debug implementations do not exist in your release code.